# Installation of sendmail

Tags: 16.10, ubuntu-gnome, sendmail

I'm trying to install `Sendmail`, but I got some "Warnings". Could anyone is able to tell me what I have to do to fix it?

[image]

Comment: Do you really need Sendmail? Postfix provides the same functionality, and is a lot more user-friendly (although e-mail is a complicated business regardless of your choice of MTA).

Comment: Nice call @fkraiem; Postfix is a nice choice!

Answer (score 0):

It's referring to [this page](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/whoami.html) from the readme, which tells you how to specify your hostname.

The warning is informing you that your hostname won't work outside your local network. Sendmail attaches your hostname as the sender of the message, but it is going to be useless on the other end because people outside your local network can't find the machine jeremie-MacBookPro. You should specify a hostname that can be resolved from anywhere, like jeremies-mbp.example.com.

Depending on your usage, this may or may not be a proper domain. If you're planning on sending mail through your laptop, I would suggest reading up on using sendmail with a relay host (So it only ever connects through your gmail account for example). Otherwise you're going to suffer some serious availability issues having your MacBook be your Mail Transfer Agent for your domain.